# .net - linux timezone interoperability

Tags: c++, .net, linux, timezone

I have a windows server and bunch of linux clients connected to this server. Linux clients will be connecting to the server and will be sending some messages which include some datetime information. In these messages I am thinking about sending UTC datetimes instead of local datetimes. And server will persist these UTC datetimes. Which seems to be the best way as far as I read on internet.

I am thinking about saving client's timezoneinfo as well so that I can calculate client message datetime if timezones differ. so will the timezone info that I get from linux using c++ be compatible with .net frameworks timezoneinfo class? Or do I need to build some sort of intelligence to make them compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the PublicDomain package?  Here's a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19680/How-to-Use-the-Olson-Time-Zone-Database-in-NET) specifically to using the Olsen Timezone DB in .NET.  This should let you interop with Linux style timezones inside .NET.